# sum non-unique lines for multiple files

Tags: awk

I would like to combine (sum) the values for all lines that are not unique in each file: I have 96 of those files. I was trying:

```
for f in file*
do
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' "$f" > "out${f#merge}"
done
```

file1:

```
rsRNA-8458-n    3
rsRNA-849-n 0
rsRNA-8617-n    0
rsRNA-946-n 0
rsRNA-9538-n    1
rsRNA-9811-n    1
rsRNA-9811-n    3
rsRNA-9815-n    0
```

file2

```
rsRNA-552-n 25
rsRNA-552-n 29
rsRNA-5722-n    0
rsRNA-6330-n    2
rsRNA-6330-n    0
rsRNA-6382-n    2
rsRNA-6382-n    8
rsRNA-6382-n    0
rsRNA-6382-n    0
rsRNA-6382-n    5
rsRNA-6430-n    0
```

Comment: Looks good to me; what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your script will currently write the unique sums to each file, outputting each to an file like `outfile1`.  Because you're asking a question about it, I'm going to assume you want to sum across all files.  Here's a GNU awk script that will either sum the unique entries per file(default) or across all the files, and sort the output in either case based on the index strings used in array `a`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" }

lf != FILENAME {
  if( !merge ) {
    output()
    delete( a )
  }
  lf = FILENAME
}

{ a[$1]+=$2 }

END { output() }

function output() {
  fname = "out" (!merge ? lf : "")
  for(k in a) {
    print k, a[k] > fname
  }
}
```

If you put that into a file called `merge.awk` and make it executable you can run it like:

```
./merge.awk file*
```

which will create the same kind of `outfile1`, `outfile2` files you get now(though sorted).  If instead, you initialize `merge` with a truthy value using the `-v` flag like:

```
./merge.awk -v merge=true file
```

all the output will go into a file simply named `out` after reading all the input files in to the same array `a`.

Here's an annotated version:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" } # GNU array sorting

lf != FILENAME {          # when the FILENAME changes
  if( !merge ) {          # output array a when merge variable is unset
    output()              # (which is the default for awk variables)
    delete( a )           # delete the array after output() to reset
  }
  lf = FILENAME           # track the last filename in lf
}

{ a[$1]+=$2 }             # sum values of the same key in array a

END { output() }          # output the contents of a

function output() {                  # define function output()
  fname = "out" (!merge ? lf : "")   # adjust the fname when merging
  for(k in a) {                      # sorted in gawk via PROCINFO
    print k, a[k] > fname            # write the contents of array a
  }
}
```

If you only every want all files merged, you could more simply do:

```
 awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}' file* > out
```

and append `| sort` to sort them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear at all what `all lines that are not unique in each file` means but assuming your awk script does what you want for one file - Again, you do not need shell loops, just let awk process all the files at once.

Using GNU awk for ENDFILE:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} ENDFILE{for(i in a) print i, a[i] > (FILENAME".out"); delete a}' *
```

If that's not what you wanted the edit your question to clarify and provide the expected output given the 2 input files you have posted.